# Check if variable data exists into params - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, parameters

I have one or more Order Details into my database for each order.

Supposing the following code:

```
# order_detail.rb

def self.by_order_id(order_id)
    where("order_id = ?", order_id)
end

def self.process_order_details(order, order_details_params)
    @order_details = OrderDetail.by_order_id(order.id)

    # answer here...
end
```

How can I check which details on `@order_details` were not sent as param into `order_details_params`

Comment: In order to answer this, I think I'd need to understand a bit better what @order_details is.  I'm guessing it's a list of details but is it multiple orders of multiple details?  I think seeing the form that generated the params would give me a better picture.

Comment: Just details for an order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** order details is similar to

```
order_details.detail_name
order_details.detail_date
order_details.detail_price
```

and order_details_params is like

```
order_details_params[:detail_price] etc
```

to return missing attributes in the order_details_params

```
@order_details.attributes.map {|k,v| k}.each do |detail_attrib|
  [DO SOMETHING] if order_details_params[detail_attrib.to_sym].blank?
end
```

eg. This outputs an array of missing attributes

```
missing = Array.new
@order_details.attributes.map {|k,v| k}.each do |detail_attrib|
  missing.push detail_attrib if order_details_params[detail_attrib.to_sym].blank?
end
```

--

Rich Peck edit

You could refactor the last loop as:

```
@order_details.attributes.each do |detail_attrib, v|
  missing.push detail_attrib if order_details_params[detail_attrib.to_sym].blank?
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. Much cleaner loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several [anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) with the accepted answer:

1. Params are not accessible in the `model`
2. You're using `where` to presumably pull a *single* record (should be [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by))
3. You're assuming your data integrity is false (which should not be the case)

---

> How can I check which details on `@order_details` were not sent as param

In other words.... *how can I check for missing submission data?*

[`Validations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

```
#app/models/order_detail.rb
class OrderDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
   validates  :name, :date, :price, presence: true
   scope      :by_order_id, ->(id) { find_by order_id: id } #-> OrderDetail.by_order_id(2)
end
```

This is the correct way to handle the [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) of the `OrderDetail` model. The validation will fire both on `create` & `update`, assuring that any data inputted into the model will be validated *before* it's stored:

```
@order_detail = OrderDetail.new order_detail_params
@order_detail.save #-> false, will return errors
```

--

Of course, the accepted answer *will* work programmatically.

However, in the pursuit of [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), you'll want to refactor with the above validation pattern.